# POST jquery Array question

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My firebug is finally giving me the post data ineed:

```
fileid  614
foldername  22
tagid   tagid%5B%5D=67&tagid%5B%5D=48
```

But now i dont know how to POST that array. Here is my php process file.

```
$fileid = $_POST['fileid'];
$tagid = $_POST['tagid']; 

$limit = count($tagid);

for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++) {

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO fileTagged (tag_id,file_id) VALUES  ('$tagid[$i]','$fileid')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error()); 
 }
```

The query just inserts the letter t in the tag_id column.
My post script was was made to handle a comma separated array so i think i need to implode or something but im not really a smart cookie.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Cheers.
John

Comment: Your title makes this sound like a jQuery question doing a POST. The text makes it sound like that part's working, and you're trying now to figure out how to *process* the posted data via PHP. Which is it? (Both?)

Comment: Yes i realized after that my title is stupid, sorry. I am trying to work out how to write the process.php file to insert the data into new rows with a file id for each tag instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$fileid = $_POST['fileid'];
$tagid = $_POST['tagid']; 

$i=str_replace('tagid%5B%5D=','',$tagid);
$j=explode('&',$i);

$limit = count($j);

for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++) {

   $sql2 = "INSERT INTO fileTagged (tag_id,file_id) VALUES  ('$j[$i]','$fileid')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

 }
```

Comment: Looks like it worked a treat, i see that you have cleaned up the tagid first. Thank you for that. I will give it a green tick as soon as i finish testing.

Comment: Quick Question, could the ampersand have been replaced with a comma?